# Бесплатна ли ubuntu для организаций

Tags: linux, ubuntu, лицензирование, юридические-аспекты

Подскажите для организации является ли ubuntu бесплатной и нужны ли какие-либо документы для проверяющих органов

Comment: Она бесплатна, точнее лицензия явно разрешает ее получать бесплатно, как впрочем и за деньги. Ограничений нет, если вы купите её у кого-нибудь за 1000$ за штуку - это не будет нарушением лицензии, не будет нарушением лицензии и последующая перепродажа или передача бесплатно, в том числе купленного варианта. А вот как на практике разруливается и проводится по организации и проводится ли сам бы с удовольствием послушал.

Comment: смотря для каких организаций. Если организация государственная, то скорее всего будет нужна копия, прошедшая проверку ФСБ и прочих структур, а это автоматически означает, что придется платить. При этом платить будете не за дистрибутив, а за подтверждающую бумажку. Это действительно по крайней мере для рабочих мест, с которых проводится работа с персональными данными. Т.е. здесь лучше спрашивать у самих проверяющих органов, они точнее скажут

Comment: Организация типа ООО, хотим просто ради экономии сделать сервер терминалов. Вот и возникает вопрос будет ли в данном случае данное ПО бесплатным, вернее можем ли мы его так использовать.?

Comment: обязательно следует указывать государство, резидентами которого являются «организация и проверяющие органы».

Comment: @alexandrovdi Для ООО будет бесплатна. И Ваша цель - терминальный сервер, будет абсолютно бесплатна для Вас.

Answer (score 1):

### Бесплатность Ubuntu

**Ubuntu** - это лишь **сборник программ** (пакетов), которые сами идут со своими лицензиями (GPL, MIT и т.п.) для каждого пакета.

На данный момент, [политика разработчиков Ubuntu](http://www.ubuntu.com/about/about-ubuntu/licensing) при выборе пакетов, которые будут распространяться вместе с Ubuntu такова, что в неё НЕ будут входить пакеты с "не свободными" лицензиями.

Под "не свободными" лицензиями, что касается финансовой их части, надо понимать то, что они запрещают использовать программы в коммерческих целях и ещё могут требовать плату за приобретение или использование программы.

В Ubuntu же такие программы не пользуются популярностью, ибо там отдают предпочтение их "свободным" собратьям, которые не требуют плату (хотя это и не запрещено, например в тех же лицензиях GPL) за их приобретение или использование.

Поэтому "ООО АБВ" может бесплатно скачать Ubuntu, например с официального сайта [ubuntu.com](http://www.ubuntu.com/about/about-ubuntu/licensing) и использовать её в коммерческих целях, в рамках закона естественно.

### Документы для проверок

Как правило, единственный документ, который имеется для конкретной программы из Ubuntu, это её лицензия, текст которой, при необходимости, вы можете распечатать.

Подробнее же о проверки подлинности ПО в офисах, предлагаю ознакомиться с данной [статьёй](http://www.tralcomplex.ru/index.php/press-centr/licensing/212-2011-07-06-10-11-04.html).